# sending email upon hitting submit in html or php

Tags: php, html, forms, user-input, email

I have a simple site with 3 input forms: a first name, last name, and email address fields for the user to fill out. I want them to be able to fill those 3, and when hitting submit, an email to be generated with some autofilled text, for example:

email: what the user put as their email
the subject will be something I make, like, "regarding your **_**"

and the body of the email to use their first and last name they entered like so:

Dear **__ __**,

click here to fill out this bla bla bla etc

How would I go about doing this?

any helpful links or tutorials would be fantastic

Comment: do you know java? i can develop this using java if you want then i can post the codes

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: i do know java but im required to use html and php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make a simple html and process it by php. You can do like this : 
index.php:

```
<form action='sendmail.php' method='post'>
      <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Firstname</td>
            <td><input name="firstName" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>LastName</td>
            <td><input name="firstName" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Lastname</td>
            <td><input name="lastName" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td><input name="email" /></td>
        </tr>
             <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type='submit' value='send' /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

sendmail.php:

```
$firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
$lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

//build email content
$emailSubject = "Email subject";
$mailContent = "Regarding ".$firstName." ".$lastName;
$mailContent .= "more content here";

//send mail
if(mail($email,$emailSubject,$mailContent)) 
    echo "mail send successful";
else
    echo "mail send fail";
```

NOTICE: I suppose that all the input param is valid for send mail. You should add more validation for input field.

Comment: your answer is more what im lookin for, but how would i get it to send? like make a button and onclick = what should get called to send that email? srry new to php

Comment: sorry. I missing send button for you. Please see my post's edit.

Comment: the php code is correct.  probably what you are missing is a mailserver.

Comment: don't need. I use phpmail for send. mail config is needle if you use mail server like smtp.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use the basic mail function within PHP as it does not protect you against header inject (open relay etc).

Take a look at one of these:
- http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mail.message.html
- http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/email/email.html
NB: They can be used outside of the MVC framework, i.e just as a mail library

Answer (score 0):

This short code for this...i hope its clear to you and will help to you, there is a lot of tutorials ......just try to search in google

```
foreach($_POST as $field_name=>$field_val)
{


        $message = $message. $field_name . " : $field_val \n";
}

//email code

$headers = "From: Feedback <".$email.">";
mail($email_to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```